# Multiplying Inequalities in Asymptotic Analysis

Tags: math

I am trying to prove something, and I'm not sure if my math is correct. Simplified down, let's say we have:

`a < b < c`

`d < e < f`

If all of these are positive values, is it legal to do:

`a*d < b*e < c*f`

If so, is there a property that I can cite?

This is a homework problem, so I'm looking for pointers in the right direction if no such property exists, rather than an outright answer.

Comment: it will be more suitable for [math stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's legal. Suppose `a < b < c` and `d < e < f`. Multiplying the inequality `a < b` by positive `d` gives `a*d < b*d`. Since we know that `d < e`, we have `a*d < b*d < b*e`. Similarly, since `b < c` and `e < f`, we get `a*d < b*e < c*e < c*f`.